# unable to install R packages in Docker container

Tags: r, docker, docker-compose

** UPDATED QUESTION **

I am running an R Studio server docker container and when login cannot import libraries (e.g. rvest) I installed in R studio with all dependecies installed.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
    version: '3.9'
    services:
    
      rstudio:
        build: ./docker/rstudio
        container_name: etl
        environment:
          - PASSWORD=yourpassword
        ports:
          - 8787:8787
```

**Dockerfile**

```
    FROM rocker/rstudio
    
    RUN apt-get clean all && \
      apt-get update && \
      apt-get upgrade -y && \
      apt-get install -y \
        python3-pip \
      && apt-get clean all && \
      apt-get purge && \
      rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
    
    RUN /usr/local/lib/R/bin/R -e 'install.packages("ODBC", repos="https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/cran/__linux__/focal/latest")' && \
       /usr/local/lib/R/bin/R -e 'install.packages("RODBC", repos="https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/cran/__linux__/focal/latest")' && \
       /usr/local/lib/R/bin/R -e 'install.packages("DBI", repos="https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/cran/__linux__/focal/latest")' && \
       /usr/local/lib/R/bin/R -e 'install.packages("rvest", repos="https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/cran/__linux__/focal/latest")'
```

Error

```
    > library(rvest)
    Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rvest’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
     unable to load shared object '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/xml2/libs/xml2.so':
      libxml2.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The file '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/xml2/libs/xml2.so' actually exists, but #2 not : '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/xml2/libs/xml2.so.2'
[image: file exists]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error message is key:

```
unable to load shared object '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/xml2/libs/xml2.so
```

These RSPM packages do not install system dependencies (as they can't, they are simple tar.gz archives; the site offers some help).  You could either just nstall the pre-made binaries from Ubuntu (`r-cran-{odbc,rodbc,dbi,rvest}`) or take care of the system-dependencies via eg

```
apt install libxml2 libodbc1
```

taking care of the XML and ODBC libraries.

*Edit:* In response to your edited question look at this search for [file `libxml2.so.2` at packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libxml2.so.2&mode=exactfilename&suite=jammy&arch=any) pointing you to [Ubuntu package libxml2](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/libxml2).  Which is exactly what I wrote earlier: you need `sudo apt install libxml2` because the CRAN (source) package does not do it for you (and cannot).  See [r2u](https://eddelbuettel.github.io/r2u/) for an alternative.

Comment: I think my question did not have all the info. I updated the question. The packages are installed from R Studio and all dependencies being installed automatically. Besides I can see the file it is complaining about actually exists. What I don't understand what this part mean?  libxml2.so.2

Comment: Thank you. I did not realize Linux xml2 and R xml2 are two different things.

Comment: Yep!  Can be tricky. Two different package managers and system -- one of the reasons [r2u](https://eddelbuettel.github.io/r2u/) is so powerful is that a) CRAN's `xml2` becomes b) the `r-cran-xml2` binary package (pre-made) and it c) has a proper dependency on `libxml2` from Ubuntu!  So you only look at CRAN  yet get both, automagically.  For key packages, these also exist in Ubuntu itself, possibly at versions slightly older than CRAN (from when the Ubuntu snapshot was made).